# Joomla event to catch/modify sql query?

Tags: sql, database, joomla, triggers, overriding

Is there an event in Joomla that one can use to catch/modify Joomla queries sql in a system plugin?

If this is not possible can we override Joomla database class? so we can add the desired event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No unfortunately no.

This is the list of events you can have in a plugin : https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events .

About the override on Joomla database, well yes you can of course. It's just a php file like the others. Just be careful with the security and when you run the updates.

Comment: Can we override it in onAfterInitialize event?